# CASE expression for two unique values being compared to another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL-Server 2008 / T-SQl

**Background:**

My query seeks to compare codes assigned to across two versions (highest value vs next highest).  The versions are assigned to the same ID (i.e. they are versions of that ID).  However, the final piece in the jigsaw (where I am struggling) is to see if the code was assigned to another version of the same ID other than the previous version.  The way the dataset is built (through use of temp tables) is so that the previous version will never have the same code as the current version.

Table 1:

```
ID | CurVer | CurCode | PrevVer | PrevCode |
------------------------
 1  |   4   | 1234    |   3     |   4321
```

Basically, although 1234 is assigned to version 4 but not to 3, I want to run a yes/no or 1/0 checker on another table, table 2, to see if was assigned to versions 1 or 2 of the same `ID`.

Table 2:

```
     ID | Ver   | Code 
    ------------------------
     1  |   1   | 1234 
     1  |   2   | 4321 
     1  |   3   | 4321
     1  |   4   | 1234
```

So, what I want to do is join table 2 to table 1 and introduce a column to table one which gives a '1' if the code is assigned to versions which are not the `CurVer` in table 2.

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
t1.ID
,t1.CurVer
,t1.CurCode
,t1.PrevVer
,t1.PrevCode
    ,(Case WHEN
    t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.CurVer != t2.Ver and t1.CurCode = t2.Code THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END)
FROM #table1 as t1 
LEFT JOIN #table2 as t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Without the distinct it will list the results four times for the four versions in table2, with '1's against the matching codes.  The `DISTINCT` gives me a dataset of:

```
 ID | CurVer | CurCode | PrevVer | PrevCode | Checker
-----------------------------------------------------
 1  |   4   | 1234    |   3     |   4321    |   1
 1  |   4   | 1234    |   3     |   4321    |   0
```

I don't want the '0' entries to appear, only the '1'. Obviously if there were no other match in `t2` it just shows a 0.  This works for the other `ID`s (there's only one line) as there's no '1' to handle.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to not show the '0' values and just show the '1's when the code is found against versions before the `PrevVer`.  Please also note I am doing this over a dataset of nearly 4000 IDs.

Comment: your goal is to get the list of all IDs with the result of the match or find the result for a specific ID?

Comment: The first one - all IDs with the result of the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output by below query with ignoring 0 and showing only 1 value :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         t1.ID, t1.CurVer, t1.CurCode, t1.PrevVer, t1.PrevCode, (CASE WHEN t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.CurVer != t2.Ver AND t1.CurCode = t2.Code THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                         AS Expr1
FROM            table1 AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE        ((CASE WHEN t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.CurVer != t2.Ver AND t1.CurCode = t2.Code THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is good to the extent where I can just get the 1s, which means I will have to dump these into another temp table then do 1 or NULL joined into a final temp table.  If there are any other solutions which avoid this workaround and neatly assign 0 or 1s I would be grateful however.  But good answer.

Comment: @TJB Just get the 1s is the stated question.  Null is something new.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the stated question
And you probably don't need the ditinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.ID
      ,t1.CurVer
      ,t1.CurCode
      ,t1.PrevVer
      ,t1.PrevCode
      ,1 as 'checker'
  FROM #table1 as t1 
  JOIN #table2 as t2 
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
   AND t1.CurVer != t2.Ver 
   and t1.CurCode = t2.Code;
```